# Showing $\{\sin(2^kx): k\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

How would I go about showing that the set $\{\sin(2^kx): k\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is linearly independent without using any integration. I am really stuck on this and I don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint}$

Suppose that there exists non zero scalars $a_i, 1\leq i\leq k$ such that:
$$\sum_{i = 1}^k a_i \sin(2^ix)=0 $$ 
differentiating twice we have:

$$\sum_{i = 1}^k 2^i a_i \sin(2^ix)=0 $$
doing this enough times we can obtain a system of equations with $a_i's$ as the "
unknowns" , conclude these will be zero.