# Dimension of a complex vector spacec generated by cos and sin functions

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

**The problem**

Find the dimension of the complex vector space generated by $\cos(2 \pi kx)$ and $\sin(2 \pi kx)$ with $0 \leq k \leq n$.

**My works**

Intuitively, the dimension may be $2n + 1$* because if we write this complex vector space we have

- $n = 0$ : this is generated by $(1)$ (1 elements)
- $n = 1$ : this is generated by $(1,\cos(2\pi x),\sin(2\pi x))$ (3 elements)
- $n = 2$ : this is generated by $(1,\cos(2\pi x),\sin(2\pi x),\cos(4\pi x),\sin(4\pi x))$ (5 elements)

I proved that the dimension of the complex vector space generated by $\exp \left( 2 \pi i k x \right)$, with $-n \leq k \leq n$, is $2n + 1$.

Since $\exp \left( 2 \pi i k x \right) = \cos( 2 \pi k x  ) + i \sin( 2 \pi k x  ) $ I think we should use this decomposition of $\exp$ to find the dimension of $\cos$ and $\sin$ but I don't see how...

Thank you

Comment: You should exclude $0$ as a basis function when counting dimension, that's why you got $2n+2$ and not $2n+1$.

Comment: I think $0$ can be removed from the set of generators.

Comment: Thank you, I removed the 0. So we must have $2n + 1$

Comment: You should probably prove that these functions are independent.

Comment: @PeterFranek since they may have the same dimensions, will it work if we show that it is the same complex vector space generated ?

Comment: @Tohiea I don't understand your question. Can you elaborate? In general, easiest way to show that sins and cosines are independent is to show that they are orthogonal in certain scalar product. Or [something like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2468551/showing-sin2kx-k-in-mathbbn-is-linearly-independent)

Comment: @PeterFranek Oh okay, in fact I would show that the complex vector space generated by cos and sin is equal to the complex vector space generated by exp. Because, if it is true then they must have the same dimensions. But I think that I will show cos and sin are independent (because it may not be complicated)

Comment: The complexified span of sins and cosines is equal to the span of $\exp(2\pi i k x)$ but I'm not sure if it helps. Still, you would need to show that the exps are (complex) independent and then do a few more steps to conclude real independence of the real and imaginary parts.